# Svelte: Use function from a parent component

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

In my App.svelte I have the following code with my function:

```-svelte
<script>
    import Categories from "./Categories.svelte";

    let choice = { category: false };

    export function toggle() {
         choice.category = !choice.category;
    }
</script>

{#if choice.category}
    <Categories />
{:else}
    <p>Foo.</p>
{/if}
```

In my Categories component I have the following code:

```svelte
<button id="vegetation" on:click="toggle()">
    <span>Analyse vegetation and forestry</span>
</button>
```

What I want is that: When I click on the button in the category component, the `toggle()` function should be called.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can forward the click event (without using a dispatcher). Example from the tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/dom-event-forwarding

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways:

**use events**

in this case your component would raise an event, and the parent reacts to that:

```html
<!-- Parent.svelte -->
<script>
  function something() { }
</script>

<Child on:toggle={something} />
```

```html
<!-- Child.svelte -->
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte'
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher()

  function toggle() {
     dispatch('toggle')
  }
</script>

<button on:click={toggle}>click me</button>
```

Read about events in the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#on_component_event)

**pass the function**

An alternative approach is to pass the function as a prop.

```html
<!-- Parent.svelte -->
<script>
  function parentToggle() { }
</script>
<Child toggle={parentToggle} />
```

```html
<!-- Child.svelte -->
<script>
  export let toggle = () => {} // no-operation function
</script>
<button on:click={toggle}>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Is any solution to be preferred to the other ?

Comment: @cassepipe the first one is preferred because it will look the same for both native elements and components, giving more consistency in your code.